# Sockets- Client's Send not working

Tags: java, c++, sockets

In the below code the connection between a C++ Client and Java Server is established using Sockets. That is notified by the Java Server. But the Send() in c++ client is returning -1.
Can't seem to grab the problem.

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
s_id = socket (PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(s_id<0)
{
    printf("S_id Error \n");
}
else
{
    serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port =htons (9090);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("127.0.0.1");
    int C_check = connect (s_id,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr));
    if(C_check<0)
    {
        printf("b_check Error \n");
    }
    else
    {
        IntVal temp(values); 
        char *Char=new char[sizeof(temp)];
        memcpy (&Char, &temp, sizeof(temp));
        int tempp;
        tempp=send(s_id,Char,sizeof(temp),0);
        if(tempp==-1)
        {
            printf("Nae Gya\n");
        }
    }
}
close(s_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
memcpy (&Char, &temp, sizeof(temp));
```

should be

```
memcpy (Char, &temp, sizeof(temp));
```

`&Char` gives you the address of the local variable that points to your allocated memory.  You want to copy `temp` into the allocated memory instead.

Based on your description of the problem, I'd guess that `sizeof(temp) > sizeof(char*)` so you currently write to areas of the stack in use by other variables, including the socket handle `s_id` which gets corrupted.

Note that you also leak `Char` at present so should add `delete[] Char` after calling `send`.

Alternatively, you could avoid allocating `Char` at all if you pass the address of `temp` into `send`

```
IntVal temp(values); 
int tempp=send(s_id,&temp,sizeof(temp),0);
```